# Importing image by opening Files on iPhone using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

What I'm trying to do is importing an image by opening File on iPhone, and making that image to be appeared on `ContentView` by `Image(uiImage: self.img)` by saving the image to the `img` variable.

With this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnOVnwbkAA0), the current code can open Files and select an image, and can get the fileName of the image, but I'm keep failing at saving it to `img` variable. It seems the problem is that all I can get is just URL of the image file, not the data of the image.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the current code

```
import SwiftUI

import UniformTypeIdentifiers

    struct ContentView: View {
        @State var fileName = ""
        @State var openFile = false
        @State var img = UIImage()
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 25){
      
                //file name of the image
                Text(fileName).fontWeight(.bold)
                
                
                //showing the image opend
                Image(uiImage: self.img)
                
                
                Button(action:{
                    openFile.toggle()
                }){
                    Text("Open")
                }
                
            
            }.fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [.image]) { (res) in
                
                do{
                    let fileUrl = try res.get()
                    print(fileUrl)
                    
                    self.fileName = fileUrl.lastPathComponent
                    
                } catch{
                    print("Error happend")
                }
               
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct Doc : FileDocument {
        
        var url: String
        static var readableContentTypes: [UTType]{[.audio]}
        
        init(url : String) {
            self.url = url
        }
        
        init(configuration : FileDocumentReadConfiguration) throws {
            url = ""
        }
        
        func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
           
            let file = try! FileWrapper(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: url), options: .immediate)
            
            return file
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wanted this

```
do{
    let fileUrl = try res.get()
    print(fileUrl)
    
    self.fileName = fileUrl.lastPathComponent

    fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl), 
                       let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        self.img = image
    }
    fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    
} catch{
    print("Error happend")
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi,tnhis worked perfect for loading image! However, still haven't figured out how to save do core data, as img is an UIImage() and core data need to save as data. A

ny idea how to save as data?

let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.id = UUID()
        // fix me: need to save image as data, not UIImage
        newItem. img = self.img